# how to use bottle for API-server

Tags: python, bottle

I use bottle framework to set up simple web service.
When submitting  data from client, how to judge this packet is through POST or GET method?
the field among header??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the method of the current request, use `bottle.request.method`. The documentation can be found here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.method.

This example shows a little route that returns the method that the client used to request the view.

```
from bottle import route, request

@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Method is " + request.method
```